# Maximization via Lagrange multipliers vs. substitution and partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the example of maximizing $x^2 y z$ under the constraint that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$.

One way to do this is to use lagrange multipliers, solving the system of equations

$$2xyz = 2x \lambda$$
$$x^2 z = 2 y \lambda$$
$$x^2 y = 2 z \lambda$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$$

---

However, couldn't you just substitute $x^2 = 5 - y^2 - z^2$ into the expression you want to maximize to get: $y z \left(-y^2-z^2+5\right)$

and then just maximize that by setting the $y$ and $z$ partial derivatives equal to zero?

Then you just have to solve the arguably simpler system of equations:

$$3 y^2 z+z^3=5 z$$
$$y^3+3 y z^2=5 y$$

where the $z$s and $y$s cancel out nicely on both sides.

Why is maximize by lagrange multipliers necessary when you can always substitute and maximize the resulting function?

When should you choose one over the other?

Comment: Sometimes it is difficult to use the constraint function to eliminate variables.  Anyway, Lagrange multipliers are often easier.

Comment: @lulu Perhaps, but if the substitution is nasty, wouldn't it be likely that taking the derivative would also yield a nasty function, making both methods equally hard?

Comment: Not at all:  Maximize $2x+3y$ on the unit circle.

Comment: Or the constraint could be a relatively simple function that only defines the variables as implicit functions of each other, as in $e^{xy}$.  Still easy to work with via Lagrange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to substitute like this, be careful to make sure you're not throwing out information when you do. For instance, the initial constraint of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$ implies in particular that $y^2 + z^2 \leq 5$. If you blindly substitute $x^2 = 5-y^2 - z^2$ as above, you'll end up trying to maximize $yz(5 - y^2 - z^2)$ with no constraint on $y$ or $z$ whatsoever, when in fact you should maximize it on the disk $y^2 + z^2 \leq 5$.

Comment: Once you find all local maxima of $yz(5-y^2-z^2$ can you not then manually check for those which satisfy the constraint $y^2 + z^2 \leq 5$?

So when would you advise maximizing using lagrange vs plain partial derivatives.

Comment: I'm not advising one over the other. However, in your comment, there is what sounds like a mathematical error: one must consider the possibility which maximizing a function on $z^2 + y^2\leq 5$ that that maximum lies on the boundary $z^2 + y^2 = 5$. If that were the case (it's not for this particular example but could be in another example) the maximum may not appear as a local maximum of the unconstrained function.